# Intuition behind the following theorem of Reeb?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, dg.differential-geometry, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

What is the intuition behind the following theorem of Reeb?

> If a compact manifold admits a function with only two critical points  which  are non degenerate, it is homeomorphic to the sphere.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morse_theory

Comment: A Morse function on a smooth manifold $M$ gives rise to a handlebody decomposition of $M$, with an $i$-handle for each index $i$ critical point. In the case of Reeb's theorem, there is one index $0$ critical point (minimum) and one index $n$ critical point (maximum), and so $M$ is obtained by attaching an $n$-handle to a $0$-handle, i.e., gluing two $n$-balls by identifying their boundary $\mathbb{S}^{n-1}$'s. However, this is simply $\mathbb{S}^n$ (Alexander's trick).

Comment: This question may be helpful: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1270099/proof-of-reebs-theorem-without-using-morse-lemma